# libreoffice massive text color change

Tags: text, colors, openoffice.org, libreoffice

Is there a way to change all occurrences of a specific color in a text in LibreOffice or Openoffice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes: With cursor in the `find` box:

- hit "`more options`" in the `Search & Replace` dialogue;
- click on "`Format...`";
- select "`Font effects`";
- select the color to search for;

Repeat the same for the `replace` box, selecting the desired new color (or "`Automatic`" to reset it to the default).

Comment: would be nice if this was extendable for table-border-colours, too. any ideas? (other than moving to TeX, which I'm in the process of doing anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via [AltSearch](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer) extension:

[image]

Comment: The link is invalid.