# how to apply color to a specific font in the text in Libre Office?

Tags: fonts, colors, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I have written a report in Libre Office mainly with Arial font and now it is almost done. I have decided to change the color of some programming code which are in courier new font. I now want to apply a different color other than black only to those courier new fonts. Can some one tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LibreOffice Writer:

- Menu 'Edit' / 'Find & Replace'
- Button 'More options' / 'Attributes'
- Tab 'Font' --> choose 'Courier New Font'
- Tab 'Font effects'
- Option 'Font color'  --> Choose new color

This question is similar to [libreoffice massive text color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943748/libreoffice-massive-text-color-change)